# In PHP xmlparser, why can't I store a global from my character_data_handler()?

Tags: php, global-variables, xml-parsing

(or Here are the code essentials:

```
$host = "";
...
xml_set_character_data_handler($xmlparser, "tagContents");
...
function tagContents($parser, $data) { 
    global $current; 
    global $host;
    if ($current == "HOST") { 
        $host = $data;         // Trying to store a global here
    }
    if ($current == "PATH") { 
        echo $host.$data;      // But its null when I get here.  WHY??
    }
}
```

I am trying to append the path to host like this to create a one-line URL, because xmlparse puts a newline after each echo.  So alternately, if anyone could tell me how to prevent the newline, that would solve my problem too!

By the way:

- I also tried referencing the super-global $GLOBALS['host'] with the same result
- I only have PHP4 available from my host server ([otherwise I'd use SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php))

Thanks,
bob

Answer (score 0):

Try to use superglobal $GLOBALS['host'] its faster anyway. Here is your fixed code

```
$host = "";
...
xml_set_character_data_handler($xmlparser, "tagContents");
...
function tagContents($parser, $data) 
{ 
    global $current; 

    if ($current == "HOST") { 
        $GLOBALS['host'] = $data;         // Trying to store a global here
    }
    if ($current == "PATH") { 
        echo $GLOBALS['host'].$data;      
    }
}
```