# how to parse google contact feed (xml or json) using php

Tags: gdata-api, gdata, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to parse the google contact feed using php, below is the example of the xml feed that i get from google

```
<entry>
        <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sample%40gmail.com/base/63a9d180dd7f506</id>
        <updated>2010-11-23T10:00:40.848Z</updated>
        <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
        <title type='text'>@@@@@@this is the sample title i need to get@@@@@</title>
        <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo' type='image/*' href='@@@@@this is the link i need@@@@@'/>
        <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sample40gmail.com/full/680dd7f506'/>
        <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sample%40gmail.com/full/0dd7f506/12940848000'/>
        <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='@@@@@@@@here is the address that i need to get@@@@@@@' primary='true'/>
    </entry>
```

how to parse out those information that i have marked using php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php parse xml string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630866/php-parse-xml-string)

Comment: Not an exact, but really not gdata specific, just need to know how to parse XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630866/php-parse-xml-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the result into Json ..(For easy parsing )

Call the API with the parameter "alt=json" You will get results in Json format ..