# How do I load a xml file with PHP?

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

I have an XML code like as given below

```
<response-code>100</response-code>

<tktname>m1318049ebc11833623372</tktname>

<abc-id>1237829</abc-id>
```

I want to fetch the tktname from the XMl using PHP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630866/php-parse-xml-string

Comment: BTW, that's not valid XML. If you're going to parse it with any standard XML parser, you'll need to add a single tag surrounding the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php?

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<test>'.$yourcode.'</test>');
print $xml->tktname;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use xml_parse to create your own parser: http://www.php.net/manual/de/intro.xml.php. xml_parse is part of php so it's likely to be installed even on shared hoster. Or you want to use DOM-XML a php extension: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php