# Parsing a XML response

Tags: php, api, curl

I have been working on the Saia Carrier API and have it giving me values albeit they are not very appealing. I would like to parse the values and put them into variables so I can display them neatly in a table.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$postdata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Create>
<UserID>XXX</UserID>
<Password>XXX</Password>
<TestMode>Y</TestMode>
<BillingTerms>Prepaid</BillingTerms>
<AccountNumber>XXX</AccountNumber>
<Application>Outbound</Application>
 <OriginZipcode>44483</OriginZipcode>
 <DestinationZipcode>90077</DestinationZipcode>
 <Details>
     <DetailItem>
        <Weight>100</Weight>
        <Class>85</Class>
    </DetailItem>
 </Details>
</Create>';


  $url = "http://www.saiasecure.com/webservice/ratequote/xml.aspx";

  $ch = curl_init($url);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: text/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
                 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);

                       $status = $info['http_code'];

                echo $status;
                    echo '<pre>';
                print_r($response);

?>
```

Comment: It's XML, just parse it. You practically answered this yourself ^^

Comment: possible duplicate of [php parse xml string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630866/php-parse-xml-string)

Answer (score 0):

I've always used PHP's SimpleXML library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

This creates a pretty basic object that is easy to use and traverse.

This is an example of traversing with the `children()` function from the site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
'<person>
 <child role="son">
  <child role="daughter"/>
 </child>
 <child role="daughter">
  <child role="son">
   <child role="son"/>
  </child>
 </child>
</person>');

foreach ($xml->children() as $second_gen) {
    echo ' The person begot a ' . $second_gen['role'];

    foreach ($second_gen->children() as $third_gen) {
        echo ' who begot a ' . $third_gen['role'] . ';';

        foreach ($third_gen->children() as $fourth_gen) {
            echo ' and that ' . $third_gen['role'] .
                ' begot a ' . $fourth_gen['role'];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

You can also retrieve attributes via the `attributes()` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<a>
 <foo name="one" game="lonely">1</foo>
</a>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->foo[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

Just added:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

and changed:

```
print_r($response);
```

to:

```
 print_r($xml);
```