# Expat Parser vs Dom Parser in php

Tags: php

when should i go for Expat parser rather Dom Parser and vice versa ? What is the difference between these parsers ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Answer (score 1):

The `xml_parser_` functions give you a stream of SAX-style callbacks as the file is consumed. It's up to you to handle or store them appropriately as they come in, linearly in document order.

(XMLReader is another serial-access parser with an imperative rather than event-based interface, which can be useful particularly for more rigidly-defined data formats.)

The `DOMDocument` loaders read the entire XML content into memory and give you a simple object-like means of querying any part of the document. For random-access tasks this is much easier to cope with, but it's also much less efficient for large documents.

Answer (score 1):

Expat is a SAX parser.

Here's a comparison between SAX and DOM parser

SAX:

1. Does not load the XML into memory
2. Top to bottom traversing
3. Event driven and works incrementally.

DOM:

1. Loads XML into memory. Hence occupies more memory.
2. Traverse in any direction.