# How to extract XML response i php

Tags: php, xml

I am using USPS(http://www.usps.com) for rate calculation between 2 zip codes. USPS accepts xml and returns response in xml. I want extract response data of the xml by php. show me a easy way to extract xml in php. thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's simplexml http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

You can create an object from an xml string :

```
$xml_string = file_get_contents('path/to/xml/url'); 
// Convert API feed to xml object 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
```

You can access any value by traversing the object for example :

```
$name = $xml->person->name;
```

with the xml looking like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<some_root>
<person>
<name>My_name</name>
</person>
</some_root>
```

Its not called simple xml for any other reason. Have a good look at the documentation, theres really a lot of cool stuff relating to xml and the handling of that.

Comment: you can also use `simplexml_load_file()` for a xml file itself

Answer (score 0):

Use `XMLReader` class.

Documentation for it you can find at http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php