# storing multiple form values to xml file

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to storing multiple form values to xml file using php but here i am able to store only one time posted value.if i post next time it is getting updated.How to make them remain

I am getting values in variables.

```
$xmlBeg = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>";
     $rootELementStart = "<$u>"; 
     $rootElementEnd = "</$u>"; 
     $xml_document= $xmlBeg; 
     $xml_document .= $rootELementStart;
      $xml_document .= "<box>"; 
        $xml_document .= $con; --//it is getting value of posted
        $xml_document .= "</box>";
```

Comment: So is this a problem of naming the saved file according to user/client specific information...?  (ie session, cookie, ip, user agent, etc).  Not quite clear yet without more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with XML you are better of using one of [PHP's XML extensions](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).

Here is the equivalent of your code with DOM:

```
$dom  = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1'); // utf-8 would be better though
$root = $dom->createElement($u);              // create root element
$box  = $dom->createElement('box', $con);     // create box element with content
$root->appendChild($box);                     // make box a child of root
$dom->appendChild($root);                     // make root the document root
echo $dom->save('filename.xml');              // save
```

This would save the XML in a file called *filename.xml*.
You can load XML from file with `$dom->load('filename.xml')`.

Also see

- [some of my answers about DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+DOM) for other usage examples
- [Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php/3616044#3616044).