# Parsing XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a simple xml file.  I know which fields it will have ahead of time.  What can you guys recommend is the best way for me to get the value of those fields using php?

Thank you :)

Comment: Simplexml is nice: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: +1 for Simplexml (and for everyone else who suggested it too)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) is great for quick reading/writing of XML files. Here's an example:

```
<root>
   <node>
      <sub>Text</sub>
   </node>
</root>
```

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('xml_file.xml', 0, true);
echo $xml->node->sub; // Displays "Text"
```

Answer (score 5):

[Simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with [XML Parser](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php), however the nice and simply way is to use [SimpleXML](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)