# RexExp in PHP for this pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need help with getting a part of an XML file with tags like this:

`<SomeTag><![CDATA[TEXT I WANT HERE]]></SomeTag>`

I've been playing around with RexExp for this, and can't get it right.
Can you suggest the proper way please?

EDIT:
Not interested in XML parsing for this particular case.
 can be anything, not just "SomeTag". Same with "Text I want here".

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php/3616044)

Comment: This is not about XML parsing, that was just an example. I'm want to be better at RegExp. Not a real project. :)

Comment: *"I need help with getting a part of an XML file with tags like this"* **is** about XML Parsing, especially since you say the tags are generic in one of the comments below. Regex can parse XML but you dont want to do that when there is parsers for that available that will do this much more reliable than your custom Regex.

Comment: Not neccesarily in my oppinion. It may be better to deal with XML with an XML parser, but I want to know how to do this with RegExp. It's a valid question in my oppinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With http://regexp.zug.fr/ I write un 5 sec a very simple pattern

```
preg_match_all("`<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>`U", $source, $matches);
```

Comment: Another fine list of tools is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Comment: At least match against the full cdata start and end tag.  You can have a nested `]` inside the CDATA (which will break your regex), but you can't have a nested `]]>`.  So change your regex to `#<\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>#` if you want to use one.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.simplexml.php).

Comment: Care to explain why instead of just throwing your opinion at the OP?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I know about XML parsing, I am however curious about RegExp for this particular case.

Comment: @Gordon: ... ? ... "possible duplicate of Best XML Parser for PHP – Gordon 6 mins ago"

Comment: @Gorden: you are implicitely seconding my suggestion.

Comment: no, I'm not. There is more answers than just the Accepted Answer in there. Also, I didnt complain about you using SimpleXML because I think it's right or wrong. I complained about you not putting an explanation for suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

As everibody else suggested use an xml parser for this job. The code bellow will show you how to do it with regex but it's not the proper way of doing things!

```
$string = '<SomeTag><![CDATA[TEXT I WANT HERE]]></SomeTag>';

preg_match_all('/<sometag><\!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]><\/sometag>/i', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
preg_match_all('/<\!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]>/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Hi, <SomeTag> is generic, it can be anything.

Comment: see the second example then , or use `/<[a-z0-9_-]+><\!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]><\/[a-z0-9_-]+>/i` but carefull this will match only if the tag has a to z,0 to 9 and _ - characters in it .

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need RegEx for this. Simple `strpos` is enough:

```
$start = strpos ($text, '<SomeTag><![CDATA[');
$end = strpos ($text, ']]></SomeTag>', $start);
return substr ($text, $start, $end - $start);
```