# Fatal error: Allowed Memory size of 67108864 in opencart

Tags: php, .htaccess, memory, memory-management, opencart

I'm using opencart. In my admin page when I access `CATALOG>PRODUCTS` (I have 73 products - Totally I have four pages). When I access my second page it shows this following error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4000 bytes) in /home/justborn/public_html/system/library/image.php on line 34
```

But, I can access first, third and fourth page. I have tried this solution ([Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4459414 bytes) in writing an xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833868/allowed-memory-size-of-67108864-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-4459414-bytes?lq=1)) in my .htaccess file

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

But, it returns 500 Internal error.. How do I solve this Fatal error: Allowed Memory size of 67108864 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the Solution

In my admin folder I have a `php.ini` file

I have changed my `memory_limit = 64M;` to `memory_limit = 128M;`. Now it works fine.. I didn't get Fatal Error.

Comment: i was looking into your answer,was that a shared hosting ?

Comment: @utility No. its dedicated

Answer (score 2):

Check your images size in filemanager: there might be some big sized images.

I had 2.9MB size of picture which created such trouble to me.

Now, after reducing the size I've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Memory limit is more than enough.
It seems that there is some endless loop in the script that is not letting it to terminate.
Look for any for, while, do while loop in the script.
If above remedy does not works, please share code so that issue can be examined further.

Comment: Also check for bad use of arrays. For example, an array in a loop can become very large, if not reset properly.

Comment: I have found the solution @andrew

Comment: @Beginner changing the memory limit is more of a "patch". A temporary fix/solution. Detecting bad code and fixing it, it's better. Your code may work now that you have a specific number of items/records to show, but what will happen in the future when these records multiply?

Comment: @andrew : Is there any other solution for this issue?

Comment: @Beginner like anuj.dikshit and me suggested, try to find bad code practises. First, declare properly all your variables. At the end of loops, destroy/nullify everything that is not needed. Its a slow proccess to debug such errors. Perhaps if you post some relevant code we can assist you more.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the php.ini file on line 18 memory_limit = 64M; to 64 x 2 = 124 or 64 x 4 = 256 but wait ask your hosting provider does they support higher limit size if yes then it will work otherwise you are wasting your energy

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem I faced,
"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in opencart system/library/image.php on line 26"

This error appears when we upload large images (1.5 MB+ size), at the time of editing the images Opencart system/library/image.php tries to load those images and in order to load BIG images it needs more memory.

In order solve this there are two ways.
 1. For shared hosting users

1.1 Open File Manager from cPanel or FTP to your website 
1.2 Go to "public_html/image/catalog"
1.3 Look for Big Images and Download and delete those images from the server.

2. VPS - Dedicated - Cloud - Server where we can manage php.ini

2.1 In admin folder open php.ini file
2.2 Try to increase from memory_limit = 64M; to memory_limit = 128M; or more as required.

This should solve the problem.

I would personally advice to upload optimized images and use solution 1 that is deleting Big Images, this is not create any load on the server.