# Dealing with XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I'm currently working a project that has me working with XML a lot. I have to take an XML response and decrypt each text node and then do various tasks with the data. The problem I'm having is taking the response and processing each text node. Originally I was using the XMLToArray library, and that worked fine I would change the XML into an array and then loop through the array and decrypt the values. However some of the XML response I'm dealing with have repeated tags and the XMLToArray library will only return the last values.

Is there a good way that I can take an XML response and process all the text nodes and easily putting the values into an array that has a similar structure to the response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious to know why you aren't just using simplexml

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Comment: I haven't been using smimplexml because from my understand I need to know to the structure of the xml to parse it. I want my code to work with any of the possible responses without having to write a special case. Any suggestions? Am I wrong in my assumption?

Comment: @NCX001 - How do you process the *array* so far?

Comment: Currently I just loop through all the values and send them through a function that decrypts them, and sets the new values into a different array with the same structure. This isn't an issue though the problem is that the XML parser I was using doesn't work with repeated tags.

Comment: @NCX001: Weird... It seems that having an array loaded into memory is the whole purpose of the app :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Here's a small example of using it. It loads and parses XML from http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml and then outputs values of "COMMON" and "PRICE" tags of each "PLANT" tag.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml');
foreach ( $xml->PLANT as $plantNode ) {
    echo $plantNode->COMMON, ' - ', $plantNode->PRICE, "\n";
}
```

If you have any problems with adapting it to your needs, just give an example of your XML so that we can help with it.

Comment: @Brian Driscoll, done. It would be better though if author gave an example of *his* XML structure.

Comment: I'm wanting to have the code take any XML thrown at it and process all the text nodes the same. There are a ton of different responses that I'll have to decrypt and I don't want to have to make a case for each one. Any suggestions? Questions?

Comment: @binaryLV @Brian We are servants to those who ask for aide.  Ask no more of them.

Comment: @NCX001, documentation + recursion, that's all I can suggest. Although using recursion might not be the best solution, as there is a limit how deep it can go.

Comment: Yeah went with SimpleXML, it seems I'm going to have to build individual cases no matter what. It's a shame there isn't an easier way to do this. If anyone thinks of one feel free to share. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All those *XML to array* libraries are a remain of the times where PHP 4 would force you to write your own XML parser almost from scratch. In recent PHP versions you have a good set of XML libraries that do the hard job. I particularly recommend [SimpleXML](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) (for small files) and [XMLReader](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) (for large files). If you still find them complicate, you can try [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [SimpleXML](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) a try. Plus it comes by default in php so you dont need to install

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), it may offer a bit more for what you are looking for.