# Get img src within html file in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How can i get the image if I was given a URL with lots of img `src`? I am using Laravel 5.2.

This takes too long to load given that I have 6,000 links. Thanks in advance.

```
$url="$products->product_url";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  echo $tag->getAttribute('src');  
}
```

Comment: You should use an `XMLReader` instead of parsing it as a DOMDocument. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299957/xml-domdocument-optimization

Answer (score 0):

Firstable you need to find some kind of `class` of `id` of parent element that contain image that you need for example:

```
<body>
    // bla-bla-bla

    <div class="content">
        <img src="img.png" />
    </div>
</body>
```

You can do follow with ZendDomQuery:

```
$finder = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
$node = $finder->query("div[class~='content'] img");
```

Comment: And also you can specifie number of element using `nth-child()`