# Parsing XML file for use on website

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

I'm submitting a form which returns an xml format with various pieces of information.
How do I go about parsing this XML so I can display the information on a web page?

Many thanks!

Comment: Also post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/book.simplexml.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($form_xml_data);
```