# How to write the values of the XML elements to the MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have to write the values of the XML elements to the MySQL database.
For example, let's say, I have this XML document:

```
<users>
    <user>
        <name>John</name>
        <nick>nick1</nick>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>Jack</name>
        <nick>nick2</nick>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>Mike</name>
        <nick>nick3</nick>
    </user>
</users>
```

And I have to write the values to the *members* table in MySQL database. So, the *members* table must be like this:

```
+------+----------+
| name |  nick    |
+----+------------+
| John |  nick1   |
+------+----------+
| Jack |  nick2   |
+------+----------+
| Mike |  nick3   |
+------+----------+
```

And I want to do this process in PHP. If you have any idea, please comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Comment: Is this a homework question John?

Comment: Looks like a relatively straightforward process: Parse the XML using one of the parsers in the link above, then walk though it and insert each item into the database.

Comment: can anybody write the code, please ?

Comment: @John: Code written, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xmlString="<users>
    <user>
        <name>John</name>
        <nick>nick1</nick>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>Jack</name>
        <nick>nick2</nick>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>Mike</name>
        <nick>nick3</nick>
    </user>
</users>
";

$xml=new SimpleXMLIterator($xmlString);
foreach($xml as $user){
    $name=$user->name;
    $nick=$user->nick;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(name, nick) VALUES('$name', '$nick')");
}
```

The important part of the code is `new SimpleXMLIterator($xmlString)`, this will create an object that you can loop over.

Runs fine, tested.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from xml documents you must parse the document first.  There are a number of php xml parsers.  THey provide an interface in which to access the data from the xml document.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php) to load the contents of the XML data onto a php object (most likely stdClass).

The loop through the results and perform each insert.