# passing xml in php function and getting common xml with condition

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

**-----First XML-----str1**

```
<HOME>
    <USER_DETAIL>
        <LOCATION><![CDATA[MUMBAI]]></LOCATION>
        <NAME><![CDATA[RAVI]]></NAME>
        <ID><![CDATA[101]]></ID>
    </USER_DETAIL>
    <USER_DETAIL>
        <LOCATION><![CDATA[PUNE]]></LOCATION>
        <NAME><![CDATA[MANISH]]></NAME>
        <ID><![CDATA[102]]></ID>
    </USER_DETAIL>
</HOME>
```

**---Second XML----str2**

```
<USER_DATA>
    <DATA>
        <DOB><![CDATA[2/11/1959]]></DOB>
        <STATUS><![CDATA[single]]></STATUS>
        <PROFILE_PIC><![CDATA[101.JPG]]></PROFILE_PIC>
        <ID><![CDATA[101]]></ID>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
        <DOB><![CDATA[6/8/1987]]></DOB>
        <STATUS><![CDATA[married]]></STATUS>
        <PROFILE_PIC><![CDATA[102.JPG]]></PROFILE_PIC>
        <ID><![CDATA[102]]></ID>
    </DATA>
</USER_DATA>
```

I am new to XML.
I have two xml as above I want common xml with all the data of user. In two XML **common** thing is **ID of user**. so is there any way to pass xml into function and compare the id in second xml and get the detais of that perticular user and forms a required(Common with all detais) xml.
str1 and str2 is the php variable which contains the above xml respectively.

Comment: You typically wouldn't do this "in XML". You convert/parse the XML into a PHP array or object, do your merging, then output that back to XML.

Comment: @deceze K lets me try that thanks for your suggestion atleast i can start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below codes to generate a new XML, you can change the nodes based on your requirements. in case you have both XMLs in a file you can use simplexml_load_file($filename); to load the XML and assign it to $str1 and $str2

```
$str1 = "<HOME>
<USER_DETAIL>
    <LOCATION><![CDATA[MUMBAI]]></LOCATION>
    <NAME><![CDATA[RAVI]]></NAME>
    <ID><![CDATA[101]]></ID>
</USER_DETAIL>
<USER_DETAIL>
    <LOCATION><![CDATA[PUNE]]></LOCATION>
    <NAME><![CDATA[MANISH]]></NAME>
    <ID><![CDATA[102]]></ID>
</USER_DETAIL>
</HOME>";

$str2 = "<USER_DATA>
<DATA>
    <DOB><![CDATA[2/11/1959]]></DOB>
    <STATUS><![CDATA[single]]></STATUS>
    <PROFILE_PIC><![CDATA[101.JPG]]></PROFILE_PIC>
    <ID><![CDATA[101]]></ID>
</DATA>
<DATA>
    <DOB><![CDATA[6/8/1987]]></DOB>
    <STATUS><![CDATA[married]]></STATUS>
    <PROFILE_PIC><![CDATA[102.JPG]]></PROFILE_PIC>
    <ID><![CDATA[102]]></ID>
</DATA>
</USER_DATA>";

$xml1 = simplexml_load_string($str1);
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($str1);
//print_r($xml);

$tempArr = array();
foreach( $xml1 as $obj)  {
$id = $obj->ID;
$tempArr["$id"]['LOCATION'] = (string)$obj->LOCATION;
$tempArr["$id"]['NAME'] = (string)$obj->NAME;
}
foreach( $xml2 as $obj)  {
$id = $obj->ID; 
$tempArr["$id"]['DOB'] = (string)$obj->DOB;
$tempArr["$id"]['STATUS'] = (string)$obj->STATUS;
$tempArr["$id"]['PROFILE_PIC'] = (string)$obj->PROFILE_PIC;
}

//print_r($tempArr);

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');

$doc = $xml->createElement('DOCUMENT');
$doc = $xml->appendChild($doc);

foreach( $tempArr as $ky=>$val )  {

$rnod = $xml->createElement('USER_DETAIL');
$rnod = $doc->appendChild($rnod);
//$rnod = $xml->appendChild($rnod);

$dataN0 = $xml->createElement('ID');
$dataN0 = $rnod->appendChild($dataN0);

$nodV = $xml->createTextNode($ky);
$dataN0->appendChild($nodV);

foreach($val as $k=>$v)  {
    $dataN1 = $xml->createElement($k);
    $dataN1 = $rnod->appendChild($dataN1);

    $nodV1 = $xml->createTextNode($v);
    $dataN1->appendChild($nodV1);
}
}

$newXml = $xml->saveXML();
echo htmlspecialchars($newXml);
```