# XML/PHP - How to get attributes in empty elements?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm a beginner and I really need your help!
I have an XML file to parse in PHP with a list of empty elements :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<elements attribute="value" attribute="value">
  <element attribute="value" attribute="value" attribute="value" />
  <element attribute="value" attribute="value" attribute="value" />
  <element attribute="value" attribute="value" attribute="value" />
  <element attribute="value" attribute="value" attribute="value" />
  ...
</elements>
```

How can I get the value of each attribute in the "element" nodes ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Comment: there is no difference between getting attributes from empty element or non-empty elements. Also, since you are supposed to do research before asking please point out why none of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getting+attributes+xml+php helped answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you posted an invalid XML? Did you mean -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<elements attribute1="value" attribute2="value">
    <element attribute1="value" attribute2="value" attribute3="value" />
    <element attribute1="value" attribute2="value" attribute3="value" />
    <element attribute1="value" attribute2="value" attribute3="value" />
    <element attribute1="value" attribute2="value" attribute3="value" />
</elements>
```

In that case you `SimpleXML` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Comment: lolz, you are new right :D? Don't know how to accept an answer. BTW, I'm happy that it helped :)