# Use data retrieved through API with curl

Tags: php, xml, api, curl

I'm trying to retrieve data from an api using curl with this code:

```
$xml_data = '<name>foobar%</name>';

$URL = "http://www.example.com/api/foobar.xml";

$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

When I execute this php script, all works well and the correct xml data is returned in my browser. My question is, how can I parse this data?

(If you recommend I do the whole thing using a different method as curl, feel free to tell me)

Comment: See [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/188414/693207) for a list of parsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [PHP docs for curl_exec function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) - note that the return value will be true/false unless CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is enabled, in which case it will be the results of the call.

Here's an updated example that would return the data in `$output`, and get the transfer details via `curl_getinfo()`:

```
$xml_data = 'foobar%';

$URL = "http://www.example.com/api/foobar.xml";

$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($info);
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following kind of code.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output);
```

And if you need to go through it's node you can simply go through those as given in below example.

Ex:

```
$imageFileName = $xml->Cover->Filename;
```

If you need you can use xpath as well.
Ex:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath(sprintf('/lfm/images/image/sizes/size[@name="%s"]', 'extralarge'));
```

Good luck!

Prasad.

Comment: thanks. I tried it with simplexml but it won't work. $output seems to be a boolean (tested it with gettype). any ideas?

Comment: Please check your XML document is correctly encoded and valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse it

Comment: I tried it with simplexml but it won't work. $output seems to be a boolean (tested it with gettype). what shall I do?