# XML help needed for extracting xml node text and child nodes (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, dom

**Consider the following xml snippet.**

```
<s1>
 S1 Tag: s1 content 1
 <test1>Test1 Tag: content</test1>
 S1 Tag: s1 content 2
 <test2>Test2 Tag: content</test2>
 S1 Tag: s1 content 3
</s1>
```

I want to extract `<s1>` tag text (*S1 Tag: s1 content 1, S1 Tag: s1 content 2, S1 Tag: s1 content 3* ) and all of its child tags (`<test1>` and `<test2>`) along with its content (*Test1 Tag: content, Test2 Tag: content*).

The output could be in any format e.g. (finally i have to persist it in db and will retrieve to produce the same xml again)

```
  S1 tag: S1 Tag: s1 content 1

  test1 tag: Test1 Tag: content

  S1 Tag: s1 content 2

  test2 tag: Test2 Tag: content

  S1 Tag: s1 content 3
```

Comment: So many tutorials when Googling `php parse xml tutorial` ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use simplexml:

```
   $stuff = " <s1>
 S1 Tag: s1 content 1
 <test1>Test1 Tag: content</test1>
 S1 Tag: s1 content 2
 <test2>Test2 Tag: content</test2>
 S1 Tag: s1 content 3
</s1>";

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($stuff);

    $test1 = (string) $xml->s1->test1;

    write_to_db($field, $test1);
```

Comment: use the concept. actual code is not meant to work by copy/paste

Comment: hmmmmm... yes i understand .. the main problem i am facing is to retrieve s1 content and all of it child tags. actually my code just extract the only "S1 Tag: s1 content 1" content and ignore the rest

Comment: this is because you need a root node. wrap the whole thing in a node: $string = "<root><s1>
 S1 Tag: s1 content 1
 <test1>Test1 Tag: content</test1>
 S1 Tag: s1 content 2
 <test2>Test2 Tag: content</test2>
 S1 Tag: s1 content 3
</s1></root>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

echo (string) $xml->s1;

Answer (score -1):

Is it same as to strip all tags via following regex

```
preg_replace('<[^>]+>', ' ', $xmlStr)
```

Comment: In fact I want to save xml to db and then have to rebuild the xml from db again. Therefore, replacing tag will will not be helpful at all.