# PHP and XML answer from server

Tags: php, xml, response

Hello i have this part of php code

```
    $google_url = "http://uclassify.com/browse/uClassify/Sentiment/ClassifyText?readkey=jnsdnjdsnjnjsdnjsnjdsd&text=".$text."&version=1.01";

    $result = file_get_contents($google_url);


$obj = simplexml_load_string($result);

$zaab = toArray($obj);

echo($zaab);
```

and the answer i get is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<uclassify xmlns="http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema" version="1.01">
    <status success="true" statusCode="2000"/>
    <readCalls>
    <classify id="cls1">
        <classification textCoverage="0.6">
            <class className="negative" p="0.999984"/>   <-----p_value
            <class className="positive" p="1.60692e-005"/>     <-----p_value
        </classification>
    </classify>
    </readCalls>
</uclassify>
```

how can i access p_values?

no after updating it gives me an error having to do with toArray()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php) and many, many, many others.

Comment: And what does the `toArray()` function look like? What error does it give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the all **p**s attribute values by looping through all **class**es like this:

```
$classes = $obj->readCalls->classify->classification->class;
    foreach ($classes as $class) {
        $p_val = $class->attributes()->p;
        echo $p_val . "<br />";
    }
```

I see you also tried to convert the xml string to array,  probably the simplest way to do it is:

```
$json = json_encode($obj);
$xml_array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

To see the results use:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a xml parser.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Comment: no if it was a simple xml parsing problem i wouldn't post here, i updated my code dfor more info