# php regexp exclude

Tags: php, regex

I use this to clean html from font tag :

```
$html = '<font class="textmiddle" color="red">toto</font>' ;
$clean = preg_replace('/<font[^>]*>/', '', $html) ;
$clean = preg_replace('/<\/font>/', '', $clean) ;
```

It works like a charm.

But, when the html string is :

```
$html = '<font class="textmiddle" color="<%= color.importanttext %>">toto</font>' ;
```

Then the result is not the expected one :

```
">toto
```

Comment: This is a prime candidate for [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) (somebody had to) - but in all seriousness, why are you processing raw ASP code in PHP?

Comment: In short, while what you want can be done with regex, don't do it. Instead write maintenable robust code by using one of the available xml/html parsers. Check this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php

Comment: @FailedDev rather http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662 because this aint XML. In any case, this is likely a duplicate.

Comment: If you have HTML in a SGML-esque serialization (angle brackets are valid in attributes), then you need a more complex regex. Entirely doable, but not worth the effort. People here are indoctrinated and playing dumb about parsing and extracting, but it is in fact best left to those who mastered regex. If you aren't, you shouldn't ask for some code fix (that you later won't be able to maintain!)

Comment: I'm not processing ASP code in PHP. I writed a function in PHP to clean some html containing JSP tags...
Of course I made $clean = preg_replace('/<\/font>/', '', $clean) ;
for the end tag

Comment: @Gordon Yeah I think the OP got the point anyway, but thanks ;)

Comment: PoC with DOM: http://codepad.viper-7.com/8Id0Ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
    $html = '<font class="textmiddle" color="<%= color.importanttext %>">toto</font>' ;
    $clean = preg_replace('/<font\s.*">/SimU', '', $html) ;
    echo $clean;
?>
```

but notice that you get

```
toto</font>
```

in output.