# Manipulate XML document and change content in Zend Framework

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, xml-parsing

I'm building an application on Zend Framework and now there is requirement to manipulate a xml file and change few content of it so that I could use the xml as a request file to get a response from other server. Now after a googling I've seen popularity of simplexml over others but I'm not sure which implementation would be better for Zend Framework. Any suggestions would be very helpful.
My request XML file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <aa>
        <bb>
            <cc>
                <dd>
                    <ee/>
                </dd>
                <ff>
                    <Identification _FirstName="******" _LastName="*****" _Num="********">
                        <gg/>
                    </Identification>
                </ff>
            </cc>
        </bb>
    </aa>
```

Now, I need to be able to change the value of _FirstName, _LastName and Num. Which XML manipulation method should I use with Zend Framework for this and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework provides the [`Zend_DOM` library](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), which builds upon [PHP's native DOM extension](http://php.net/dom) (linkage mine):

> `Zend_Dom` provides tools for working with DOM documents and structures. Currently, we offer `Zend_Dom_Query`, which provides a unified interface for querying DOM documents utilizing both [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) and [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

If you don't need Selectors, you don't need `Zend_DOM`, but can use any of the [native XML extensions](http://php.net/manual/de/refs.xml.php).

How to use `Zend_DOM` is explained in the reference guide:

> To use `Zend_Dom_Query`, you instantiate a `Zend_Dom_Query` object, optionally passing a document to query (a string). Once you have a document, you can use either the `query()` or `queryXpath()` methods; each method will return a `Zend_Dom_Query_Result` object with any matching nodes.

So in a nutshell:

```
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($xmlString);
$results = $dom->query('Identification');
$identification = $results->current();
```

$identification will then contain a `DOMElement` which you can change like any other `DOMElement`. There is ample examples on StackOverflow on [how to change values in an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=change%20value%20in%20xml%20file%20php), so I won't repeat that here.

After you changed the `DOMElement`, you need to get hold of the `DOMDocument` to serialize the changed document back into XML. To do so, you can use

```
$doc = $identification->ownerDocument;
$doc->save('filename.xml'); // to save it to a file
$xmlString = $doc->saveXML(); // to save it to a variable
```

For an overview of X(HT)ML parsers see

- [Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php/3616044#3616044) or
- [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Hey Gordon, Thanks for the reply. I'll be using Zend_DOM library for this.

Comment: I don't think that the linked CSS Selectors standard is really supported in `Zend_DOM`. Smells a bit like marketing.

Comment: @hakre not sure to which extend they support selectors. the linkage in the quote is mine. I really just wanted to give a link to the standard here.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the following structure:

```
<Identification>
     <FirstName>*****</FirstName>
     <LastName>*****</LastName>
     <Num>*****</Num>
   </Identification>
```

And use Zend_Config_Xml class: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.xml.html

Comment: The one I wrote is an standard to request to another server so I cannot do as you suggested.