# php parser xml with curl, display only tags that i want

Tags: php, xml, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

I have a Php/ curl file

```
<?php
echo "Conversion Stats<br />"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://login.leadkitchen.com/affiliates/api/4/reports.asmx/Conversions' );
$post_array = array(
       'affiliate_id' => '123',
    'api_key' => 'abc',
    'start_date' => '10/8/2012',
    'end_date' => '10/11/2012',
    'offer_id' => '123',
    'start_at_row' => '1',
    'row_limit' => '0',
    'sub_affiliate' => 'email'
);

//url-ify the data
foreach($post_array as $key=>$value) 
{ 
    $post_array_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
$post_array_string = rtrim($post_array_string,'&');
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($post_array ));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_array_string);
$response = curl_exec($ch);



print "$response";


?>
```

And possible XML response for this

```
<conversion_response>
<success>true</success>
<row_count>1</row_count>
<summary>
<price>22.26555000000000</price>
<currency_symbol>$</currency_symbol>
</summary>
<conversions>
<conversion>
<conversion_id>221D4853</conversion_id>
<conversion_date>2011-06-24T11:51:05.117</conversion_date>
<offer_id>100</offer_id>
<offer_name>$100 Bendy's Gift Card + Free Frosti</offer_name>
<campaign_id>1781</campaign_id>
<subid_1>111770</subid_1>
<subid_2/>
<subid_3/>
<subid_4/>
<subid_5/>
<price>15.0000</price>
<disposition>Voicemail matches name</disposition>
<test>false</test>
<currency_symbol>€</currency_symbol>
</conversion>
</conversions>
</conversion_response>
```

I actually need to display only conversion_id and price in the page. I don't want other results to be displayed on the page. How do I do this?

Comment: You do that by parsing the XML, see the link for the many options that exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SimpleXMLElement` to get the elements you want

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
echo "<pre>";
echo $xml->conversions->conversion->conversion_id, PHP_EOL;
echo $xml->conversions->conversion->price, PHP_EOL;
```

Output

```
221D4853
15.0000
```