# fetch data from xml parser

Tags: php, xml, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

I would like to display the array I get from this url in a table in my website. However I have no clue where to begin. The link is

http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayer_service.php?country=usa&city=germantown&state=MD&zipcode=20876&latitude=39.2074&longitude=-77.2311&timezone=-5&HanfiShafi=1&pmethod=5&fajrTwilight1=10&fajrTwilight2=10&ishaTwilight=10&ishaInterval=30&dhuhrInterval=1&maghribInterval=1&dayLight=1&simpleFormat=xml

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You want to know where to start? [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) simple HTML parser?

```
$data = Array();
$html = file_get_html('http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayer_service.php?country=usa&city=germantown&state=MD&zipcode=20876&latitude=39.2074&longitude=-77.2311&timezone=-5&HanfiShafi=1&pmethod=5&fajrTwilight1=10&fajrTwilight2=10&ishaTwilight=10&ishaInterval=30&dhuhrInterval=1&maghribInterval=1&dayLight=1&simpleFormat=xml');

foreach($html->find('prayer') as $prayer)
{
    $data['fayr']    = $prayer->find('fayr', 0)->plaintext;
    $data['sunrise'] = $prayer->find('sunrise', 0)->plaintext;
    $data['dhur']    = $prayer->find('dhur', 0)->plaintext;
}
```