# PHP parse XML data

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have something like this:

```
  <client type="s" name="root" desc="" protocol="server" protocolext="" au="0" thid="0x15e9190">
     <request="0000" srvid="0000" time="" history="" answered=""></request>
     <times login="2013-04-16T10:59:16+0200" online="7001" idle="0"></times>
     <connection ip="127.0.0.1" port="0">OK</connection>
  </client>
```

Now, i need to parse this data into a PHP variables, something like this:

```
 $client_type = s; $name = root; $conn_ip = 127.0.0.1;
```

...and so on,is there a way to do that?

Tried bash, but it would be much easier if it can be done with php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has XML support.  I like to use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml).

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

$client_type = (string)$xml['type'];
$name = (string)$xml['name'];

$conn_ip = (string)$xml->connection['ip'];
```

Easy.

DEMO: https://eval.in/124545

Comment: Thanks for this, will test it tomorrow, a newb question: Why is there (string) in front of an $xml? And how would i extract "OK" this way?

Comment: 1. Things like `$xml['name']` are `SimpleXMLElement` *objects*, [casting to a string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in this way gets their text value (`"root"`). 2. `(string) $xml->connection`.   See also, http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic

Comment: This works great, but when i download xml file i have multiple structures as the above one, how can i do it with multiple <client></client> structures?

Comment: You'd have to make sure all the `<client>` tags are under a root element.  Then `$root->client` would be an array of elements.  Loop over `$root->client` and get the info for each item.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with a xml Parser:
https://www.php.net/xml,
[Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Comment: thanks for that, i know how to use xmlparser on a normal xml syntax <name>Mario</name> but i don't know how to do that with a value inside a tag, can you give me an example? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[`simplexml_load_file()`](https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_file) or [`simplexml_load_string()`](https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_string) loads xml as an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fetch data from a XML use Xpath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$client_type = $xpath->evaluate('string(/client/@type)'); 
$name = $xpath->evaluate('string(/client/@name)');; 
$conn_ip = $xpath->evaluate('string(/client/connection/@ip)');
```

Demo: https://eval.in/124553