# Cakephp soap client: How to send a soap request with two namespaces? can some give me some example codes?

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, soap, client

I am a new phper, now I want to use cakephp soap client to send a xml request below, but I can't implement it, can some give me some example codes? thx.

< soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:ws="http://ws.test.com"
                xmlns:xsd="http://mtest/xsd">
    < soapenv:Header/>
    < soapenv:Body>
        < ws:get_status>
            < ws:login>
                < xsd:code>ABCDEF< /xsd:code>
                < xsd:password>1UH7UHUH8HUG< /xsd:password>
            < /ws:login>
        < /ws:get_status>
    < /soapenv:Body>
< /soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
<?php

class MySoapClient extends SoapClient {

function __construct($wsdl, $options) {
    parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    $this->server = new SoapServer($wsdl, $options);
}
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) 
{ 
    $result = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version); 
    return $result; 
} 
function __myDoRequest($array,$op) { 
    $request = $array;
    $location = 'http://xxxxx:xxxx/TransactionServices/TransactionServices6.asmx';
    $action = 'http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/'.$op;
    $version = '1';
    $result =$this->__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
    return $result;
} 
}


$soapClient = new MySoapClient("http://xxxx:xxxx/TransactionServices/TransactionServices6.asmx?WSDL", array("trace" => 1)); 
$PostTransaction = $soapClient->__myDoRequest($orderRequest,$op); 
?>
```

Comment: Hi Chandu, 

Thank you for answering my question, for the last line of your example codes,
$PostTransaction = $soapClient->__myDoRequest($orderRequest,$op); 
What the $op should be? 'POST'?

like below?
$PostTransaction = $soapClient->__myDoRequest($orderRequest,'POST');

Comment: Another question, how can I set my two namespace below?
xmlns:ws="http://ws.test.com"
xmlns:xsd="http://mtest/xsd">

and how can I set my field value of 'code' and 'password', thanks so much.