# How to Parse xml data using php

Tags: php, xml

I am using travelyari api from which i am getting the deta as below. In this i want to get city names seperated. I have tried many solutions but didnt get success.Please anyone help me.

```
<APIGetCitiesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<APIGetCitiesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CRS2011AgentApi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>311</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Chiplun</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>2432</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Dhartale</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>2431</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Gaonkhadi</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>519</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Khed</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>11</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Mumbai</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>2429</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Pawas</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
```

Comment: did you tried  `simplexml_load_file`?

Comment: Yes i have tried this too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php) module of php xml to access nodes:

```
    $xmlString = file_get_contents("yourXMLFileName.xml");
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

    foreach ($xml as $out_namespace) 
    { 
        $ns = $out_namespace->getNamespaces(true);
        $child = $out_namespace->children($ns['a']);
        foreach ($child as $out) 
        { 
            echo "From City name: ". $out->FromCityName ." To city name : ".$out->ToCityName."</br>";

        } 
    }
```

Comment: @AtulSuroshe , you are welcome , accept and upvote please

Comment: You should not read the namespace by its prefix from the document. The prefix is optional and can change anywhere in the document.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SimpleXMLElement` with xpath. `//a:FromCityName|//a:ToCityName` will query `FromCityName` or `ToCityName`.

**Code**

```
<?php
$xmlString ='<APIGetCitiesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<APIGetCitiesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CRS2011AgentApi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>311</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Chiplun</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>2432</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Dhartale</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>2431</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Gaonkhadi</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>519</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Khed</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>11</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Mumbai</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
<a:CityPair>
<a:FromCityID>2433</a:FromCityID>
<a:FromCityName>Adivare</a:FromCityName>
<a:ToCityID>2429</a:ToCityID>
<a:ToCityName>Pawas</a:ToCityName>
</a:CityPair>
</APIGetCitiesResult>
</APIGetCitiesResponse>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CRS2011AgentApi');
$results = $xml->xpath('//a:FromCityName|//a:ToCityName');

foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result . "\n";
}
?>
```

**Result**

```
Adivare
Chiplun
Adivare
Dhartale
Adivare
Gaonkhadi
Adivare
Khed
Adivare
Mumbai
Adivare
Pawas
```

**Reference**

1. [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)
2. [registernamespace](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php)